Can't upload images on appwrite using react native
I'm using expo image picker to get images from the gallery , then i wanna save that image to appwrite storage, but still getting the same error
I get the error can't read property $id of undefined, I went to read documentation but still can't figure out what is wrong with my code
export async function uploadFile(file) {
  if (!file) return;

  const { mimeType, ...rest } = file;
  const asset = { type: mimeType, ...rest };

  try {
    const uploadedFile = await storage.createFile(
      config.storageId,
      ID.unique(),
      {
        name:asset.filename,
        type:asset.mimeType,
        uri:asset.uri
      }
    );

    const fileUrl = await getFilePreview(uploadedFile.$id);
    return fileUrl;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message || 'Error uploading file');
  }
}


export async function getFilePreview(fileId) {
  try {
    const fileUrl = storage.getFilePreview(
      config.storageId,
      fileId,
      2000,
      2000,
      "top",
      100
    );

    if (!fileUrl) throw new Error('Error generating file preview');

    return fileUrl;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message || 'Error generating file preview');
  }
}

export async function createPost(form) {
  try {
    const imageUrl = await uploadFile(form.image);

    const newPost = await databases.createDocument(
      config.databaseId,
      config.signalementCollectionId,
      ID.unique(),
      {
        title: form.title,
        image: imageUrl,

      }
    );

    return newPost;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message || 'Error creating image post');
  }
}


Can you share which of these functions is causing the error?
